# How to make Lambda real

Tags: c#, serialization, anonymous-function, lambda

So I use a command to save variables into a serialized file. I save the following data:

```
data.Save("ships", this.ships.Select(x => x.Name));
```

This is supposed to output an IEnumerable but instead it seems to output something different, which I'm guessing is to do with Lambda's lazy init? The error being:

```
Type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[[~~~],[~~~]]' in Assembly '~~~' is not marked as serializable.
```

The error is caused due to the fact that `this.ships` is a `non-serializable` type, compared to the return of `.Name` of type string which it should be.

So I was hoping I could find out how to make it return it's true value?

I have realised that adding `.ToList()` would work, but I was curious for the neater solution.

Comment: Without looking it up, I'm pretty sure that type *is* an `IEnumerable`. Tons of things implement that interface, and the interface does not imply serializability.

Comment: `ToList()` is pretty clean by itself. But if you don't like adding that every time you call `data.Save`, call it on the parameter inside `data.Save`.

Comment: @RajeshDhiman If you suggest edits will you please make sure you make them substantial. That is fix everything in the post there is to fix. Only backticks or indents is not enough.

Comment: @rene Sure, will do that. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @RajeshDhiman Also, please don't change my English to American. As said on the Wiki, StackOverflow's language is English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>` does implement `IEnumerable<TResult>` and, as you already know, it is not serializable.

`WhereSelectListIterator` stores the source and query definition, and allows your query to be lazy, what means it's evaluated when you need the results, not when the query is created.

If you want to serialize results of the query, you have to force the evaluation. Either `ToList()` or `ToArray` will work just fine.

```
data.Save("ships", this.ships.Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
```

To make sure that kind of error does not occur in future, you can consider changing `Save` method definition to use `ICollection<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the class on Lambda's, I wish there was more info on them. I'll use .ToList() since I can't change the Save method as it's syntax is "void Save<T>(string id, T obj);"